# HandlerMethodArgumentResolver implementation returns an empty user object

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created an implementation of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to return the current logged in user for controller methods annotated with `@CurrentUser`. However, when the `resolveArgument` method of the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` gets called, an empty user is returned. I have verified that my custom `UserDetailsService` implementation does retrieve a full user object.

The code I'm using is as follows.

The @CurrUser annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal
public @interface CurrentUser {
}
```

The HandlerMethodArgumentResolver implementation with empty user:

```
public class CurrentUserMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(CurrentUser.class) != null
                  && parameter.getParameterType().equals(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        if (this.supportsParameter(parameter)) {
            Principal principal = webRequest.getUserPrincipal();
            User user = (User) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal(); // This user is empty!!!
            return user;
        } else {
            return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
        }
    }
}
```

The calling Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<Resource<User>> currentUser(@CurrentUser User self) {

    log.debug("CurrentUserController > currentUser GET> " + self);
}
```

The loadUserByUsername of UserDetailsService that retrieves the populated user (I verified this is called first):

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
    CustomUserDetails ud = new CustomUserDetails(user);
    return ud;
}
```

The WebMvcConfigurerAdapter configuration:

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(currentUserMethodArgumentResolver());
}

@Bean
public CurrentUserMethodArgumentResolver currentUserMethodArgumentResolver() {
    return new CurrentUserMethodArgumentResolver();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you implemented your own? You could always inject already the `Principal` this is supported out-of-the-box by Spring MVC and Spring Security already has the [`@AuthenticationPrincipal`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal).

Comment: Also when using the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` as a meta annotation the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` from Spring Security still works, so no need to implement your own.

Comment: My original intention was to provide an "extended" User object that would be populated with additional data from the database. I figured it would be better to retrieve the extra information from a single piece of code instead of querying the data throughout my service implementations. As you may be suggesting, I may be making things a bit more complicated than it needs to be. I'll take a look at your suggestion and see if it will do the job. Thanks @M. Deinum for the info.

Comment: The `@AuthenticationPrincipal` just retrieves the current `UserDetails`, which, as I can tell from what you posted, is your extend user object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the issue was - the problem was in how I implemented `CustomUserDetails':

```
public static class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

    ...

}
```

I was extending my custom User class and implementing `UserDetails`. I'm not sure why, but Spring didn't like this. I since fixed the code by creating and populating a new `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`, and returning this from the call to `loadUserByUsername'.